# How to plot mean points with stat_summary groupping by color and by linetype?

Tags: ggplot2, mean, summarize

I have to plot the mean points connected by lines of a dataset that include: ID, Pre-treatment, Treatment, Time-point, and the score for each of my sample:

```
ID       Pre-treatment    Treatment      Time-point    Score
-------------------------------------------------------------
  A.1         A               Control          1           2
  A.1         A               Heat             1           3
  A.1         B               Control          1           5
  A.1         B               Heat             1           4
  A.1         C               Control          1           7
  A.1         C               Heat             1           8
  A.2         A               Control          1           3
  A.2         A               Heat             1           6
  A.2         B               Control          1           8
  A.2         B               Heat             1           6
  A.2         C               Control          1           9
  A.2         C               Heat             1           1

  A.1         A               Control          2           2
  A.1         A               Heat             2           3
  A.1         B               Control          2           5
  A.1         B               Heat             2           4
  A.1         C               Control          2           7
  A.1         C               Heat             2           8
  A.2         A               Control          2           3
  A.2         A               Heat             2           6
  A.2         B               Control          2           8
  A.2         B               Heat             2           6
  A.2         C               Control          2           9
  A.2         C               Heat             2           1
  ....
```

(the score's values are just random here).

I would like to use ggplot with this d.f and stat_summary to visualize in one single graph the data with : color = Pre-treatment and linetype = Treatment.

Ideally, I should have:

> ```
> Red and solid line  = A_Control;
> Red and dashed line = A_Heat;
> Blue and solid line = B_Control;
> Blue and dashed line = B_Heat;
> ....
> ```

I used this code:

```
d.f %>%
  
  ggplot( df, mapping = aes(x = Time-point, y = Score, 
                               colour = Pre-Treatment, linetype = Treatment, shape = Treatment))+
   geom_point()+
  stat_summary(
    aes(group = Pre-Treatment, color = Pre-Treatment),
    fun = "mean",
    geom = "line",
    size = 1)
```

But it works properly only if I use `facet_grid(Treatment ~ .)`. In this case, it separate the the plots in 2 rows. If I don't do it, it group and summarize the A_crontrol + A_Heat.

Can you help me? Where is the missing part?
Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```r
#load libraries
library(tibble) 
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)

# dataframe
d.f <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,       ~Pre_treatment,    ~Treatment,      ~Time_point,    ~Score,
  "A.1",         "A",               "Control",          1,           2,
  "A.1",         "A",               "Heat"   ,          1 ,          3,
  "A.1",         "B",               "Control",          1 ,          5,
  "A.1",         "B",               "Heat"   ,          1 ,          4,
  "A.1",         "C",               "Control",          1 ,          7,
  "A.1",         "C",               "Heat"   ,          1 ,          8,
  "A.2",         "A",               "Control",          1 ,          3,
  "A.2",         "A",               "Heat"   ,          1 ,          6,
  "A.2",         "B",               "Control",          1 ,          8,
  "A.2",         "B",               "Heat"   ,          1 ,          6,
  "A.2",         "C",               "Control",          1 ,          9,
  "A.2",         "C",               "Heat"   ,          1 ,          1,
  "A.1",         "A",               "Control",          2 ,          2,
  "A.1",         "A",               "Heat"   ,          2 ,          3,
  "A.1",         "B",               "Control",          2 ,          5,
  "A.1",         "B",               "Heat"   ,          2 ,          4,
  "A.1",         "C",               "Control",          2 ,          7,
  "A.1",         "C",               "Heat"   ,          2 ,          8,
  "A.2",         "A",               "Control",          2 ,          3,
  "A.2",         "A",               "Heat"   ,          2 ,          6,
  "A.2",         "B",               "Control",          2 ,          8,
  "A.2",         "B",               "Heat"   ,          2 ,          6,
  "A.2",         "C",               "Control",          2 ,          9,
  "A.2",         "C",               "Heat"   ,          2 ,          1
)


# graph
d.f %>%
  group_by(Time_point, Pre_treatment, Treatment) %>% 
  mutate(Score_mean = mean(Score)) %>% 
  ggplot( df, mapping = aes(x = Time_point))+
  geom_point(aes(y = Score, color = Pre_treatment, shape = Treatment)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Score_mean, color = Pre_treatment, linetype = Treatment)) +
  labs(x = "Time Point", color = "Pre Treatment")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>